# Add registration delay on AWS ECS Fargate containers

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am running an application as a Fargate service behind an ALB with a Target Group. The health check is responding after a couple minutes, but some plugins are still being deployed by Tomcat, and it takes about an extra minute for everything to finish. Since the health check is responding early, this is causing the containers to be registered/deregistered early too, which could be a potential issue. I only know when apps/themes have finished deploying by log messages.

What is the proper way of adding a delay in the registration/deregistration of containers? Should I modify the `HealthyThresholdCount`? Or should I create a custom container health check instead?

Comment: Your best bet is probably going to be adding a custom container health check that only returns healthy when the container is actually ready to receive requests.